# Can asp.net include microsoft.visualbasic namespace in a c# class?

Tags: c#, namespaces

Can we reference the Microsoft.VisualBasic namespace in C#?

for example:

```
using System;
...others...
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;
```

This question arises to try to use the VB "Choose( iVal, Val1, Val2, Val3...)" VB-function within C# code.

Thanks.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to find or write the equivalent method in C#?

Comment: Did you consider trying it?

Comment: @EricLippert : No, I did not, since I do not normally code in C#, but I came across a question about "Choose-function" not being in C#-libs and was just curious about using the VB-namespace in a C# project. To all others who responded...why did I get marked a -3 for asking a question that some gave good answers to???

Comment: Possibly because the question shows no effort. In the future, try to do some research before asking questions; it shows respect for other people's time. A brief web search would have found numerous articles on how to use VB classes in C#. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173136.aspx for instance.

Comment: Well, I did research related to the Choose-function, and I did find a reference to "build-your-own" Choose-function for C#.  That got me wondering whether C# could use the VB Choose-function.  I then researched namespaces and did not find the article you refer to in your comment. In my experience with ASP WebForms coded under VB, namespaces are used as "imports/using" statements -- not as labels within my code -- so, unfortunately, I do not know what C#-ers know about namespaces, and I asked the question to the smart StackOverflow.  I do not think I should have demerits for this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can. Don't forget to add the assembly reference as well.

For reference, [`Choose`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/824bz7dy%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) is in the `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction` class.

---

Alternatively, you can make your own `Choose` function rather easily:

```
public static object Choose(int index, params object[] choices)
{
    //note we are in 1-based land here!
    if (index < 1) return null;
    if (index > choices.Length) return null;
    return choices[index - 1];
}
```

If you look carefully, VB's `Choose` method actually takes a `double`. The documentation states it rounds the number, but in practice it appears to truncate it. If you need to replicate this functionality:

```
public static object Choose(double index, params object[] choices)
{
    return Choose((int)Math.Floor(index), choices);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the Microsoft.VisualBasic namespace in C#.